# How can I get a URL parameter with jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am sending an AJAX request and want to send the data of the URL variable with it. I have tried using PHP's `GET`, however it is not sent.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "send.php",
  data: "name=" + "<?php $_GET['name']; ?>", 
  success: function(data) {
    $("#div").html(data);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to `echo` the get variable.

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "send.php",
       data: "name=" + "<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>", 
       success: function(data) {
           $("#div").html(data());
       }
})
```

moreover, its prefer you use the object to send data.

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "send.php",
       data: {'name':'<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>'}, 
       success: function(data) {
           $("#div").html(data());
       }
})
```

Comment: or; `data: "name=" + <?= $_GET['name']; ?>, `

Comment: Ah thank you - silly mistake! Is there any benefits to sending data that way?

Comment: Yes, it's more manageable (Suppose we have `&` sign in our data, then the query string needs to escape in order to work correctly) and prefers rather than using a plain query string. And you are welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

There are two things.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "send.php",
   data: "name=" + <?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>, 
   success: function(data) {
     $("#div").html(data());
   }
});
```

First is `<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>`.

Second is missing closing bracket `$("#div").html(data());`

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "send.php",
  data: "name=" + <?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>, 
  success: function(data) {
    $("#div").html(data();
  }
});
```

Comment: answer with out explanation is not an answer at all. point why OP code didnt work and point why your answer should work..